# Why is wrapper.findAllComponents not working?

Tags: vuejs2

This is the code I have:

```js
  let routes = wrapper.findAllComponents('router-link')
  let route = wrapper.findComponent('router-link')

  console.log(routes.length) // 0
  console.log(route) // a useable component
```

I get a route with `findComponent` but `findAllComponents` returns to me an empty `wrapperArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it into a global property. Check out the [documentation](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vue-router.html#using-stubs) here

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

shallowMount(Component, {
  global: {
      stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view']
  }
})
```